# Como aplicar Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently

Tags: java, android, xml, memória

Estou usando ImageView para carregar imagens pois eu encontro erro de falta de memoria encontrei este método, pois não estou conseguindo usar. queria uma breve esplicação onde eu altero as variáveis

disponível em http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

Leia Bitmap Dimensões e Tipo

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

Coloque uma versão reduzida em Memória

```
  public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId 
      int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize uma `AsyncTask` para realizar o cálculo das imagens, evitando que a `Main Thread` fique travada!

Outra dica é você utilizar de `Composites` para renderizar essas imagens, ou seja, `ListView`, `GridView`, `RecyclerView`, etc, pois dessa forma ele apenas irá carregar em memória as imagens que estão sendo exibidas para o usuário.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa biblioteca também, vai lhe ajudar MUITO! https://github.com/square/picasso